# How to write these `if..else` conditional statements with Ternary Operators

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-8, conditional-operator

I want to write these `if..else` statements with ternary operators:

```
if((($request->city)=="98")&&($cartPrice >= 300000)&&($request->province)=="8")){
    "ort_free_delivery" => 'City sending free delivery'
}elseif((($request->city)!="98")&&($cartPrice >=300000)&&($request->province)!="8")){
    "ort_free_delivery" => 'Country sending free delivery'
}else{
    "ort_free_delivery" => '',
}
```

And here is my try:

```
( ( ($request->city)=="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)=="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "City sending free delivery" ) ); 

( ( ($request->city)!="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)!="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "Country sending free delivery" : "ort_free_delivery" == "" ) );
```

But this is wrong because there are two lines of ternary operators, and I need this condition in one line (because I'm inserting some data with DB class in Laravel):

```
    DB::table('order_detail')->insert([
        "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
        "ort_amount" => $value->price,
        "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_type" => "product",
        "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
        "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
        ( ( ($request->city)=="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)=="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "City sending free delivery" ) )
        ( ( ($request->city)!="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)!="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "Country sending free delivery" : "ort_free_delivery" == "" ) )
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ]);
```

So my question is, how can I add this conditional statement with ternary operators in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is build array and then insert

```
$data=[
        "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
        "ort_amount" => $value->price,
        "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_type" => "product",
        "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
        "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ];
```

For conditional data

```
if($request->city==98&&$cartPrice >= 300000&&$request->province==8){
    $data["ort_free_delivery"] = 'City sending free delivery';
}elseif($request->city!=98&&$cartPrice >=300000&&$request->province!=8){
     $data["ort_free_delivery"] = 'Country sending free delivery';
}else{
    $data["ort_free_delivery"] = '';
}
```

Then query

```
  DB::table('order_detail')->insert($data);
```

or

```
DB::table('order_detail')->insert([
    "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
    "ort_amount" => $value->price,
    "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
    "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
    "ort_type" => "product",
    "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
    "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
    "ort_free_delivery" =>($request->city==98&&$cartPrice >= 300000&&$request->province==8)?'City sending free delivery':
        (($request->city!=98&&$cartPrice >=300000&&$request->province!=8)?'Country sending free delivery':null),
    "created_at" => now(),
    "updated_at" => now()
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. The idea is to replace the statement after the first `:` with a second ternary. The second ternary gets evaluated only if the first condition is false.

```
    DB::table('order_detail')->insert([
        "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
        "ort_amount" => $value->price,
        "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_type" => "product",
        "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
        "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
        "ort_free_delivery" => ( ( ($request->city)=="98" ) &&  ($cartPrice>=300000) && ( ($request->province)=="8" ) ) ? "City sending free delivery" : ( ( ($request->city)!="98" ) && ($cartPrice>=300000) && ( ($request->province)!="8" ) ) ? "Country sending free delivery" : "" ) ),
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `var_dump` for testing, instead of what you have, this is what I came up with:

```
(((($request->city=="98")&&($cartPrice>=300000)&&($request->province=="8"))?var_dump('1'):((($request->city!="98")&&($cartPrice>=300000)&&($request->province=="8"))?var_dump('2'):var_dump('3'))))
```

In a more readable way:

```
(
    (
        (
            ($request->city == "98") && 
            ($cartPrice >= 300000) && 
            ($request->province == "8")
        )
        ? var_dump('1') 
        : (
            (
                ($request->city != "98") && 
                ($cartPrice >= 300000) && 
                ($request->province == "8") 
            )
            ? var_dump('2')
            : var_dump('3')
          )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ort_free_delivery" => ($cartPrice >= 300000 ? ( $request->city=="98" && $request->province=="8" ? 'City sending free delivery' : 'Country sending free delivery' ) : '')
```

**Human read code:**

If cartPrice is lower 300000 is always ''

else if both city is 98 and province is 8 at same time (AND)...

is "city sending.."

else

is "Country sending.."

**Because**:

the main distinguish rule seems that both city=98 and province=8 must be True to be 'city sending' ...

... so all other cases is 'country sending'...

... when cartprice is >= 300000